# Import xlsx file into html page via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xlsx

I want to read the data of a specific xlsx file into javascript to show them on a .html page.
For that i downloaded sheetjs.  A .xlsx parser.

But now I realized that you kinda must choose a file in the html site to read it. But I only want to use one file the whole time. Also the html site will only run local. So is there any way to get going with setting up a absolute path in the js to the file. So something like

`file= "C:\test.xlsx"`

Code example from the documemtary:

```
function handleFile(e) {
  var files = e.target.files;
  var i,f;
  for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var name = f.name;
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;

      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});

      /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
  }
}
input_dom_element.addEventListener('change', handleFile, false);
```

Comment: How are you running the local html site?  What's the server-side language?

Comment: Oh so what I want to do is just do the .html files + the xlsx file in one folder and let the html file read some data from the excel. I just open the html in a browser. There is no server involved. I just want to change the excel file from time to time manually. So .html pages read the new data from the excel.